# Cakephp validation error box

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I'm trying to use the build-in validation in cakephp 2.5

My problem is, with text fields I've got the nice jquery error message but for a select field, the message appear in a div. I don't know if I'm missing something in my select to get the error box or it's just not available for that type of field.

[image: screenshot]

```
<?php echo $this->Form->label('launch', 'Launching Site <span class="crRed">*</span>', 'crLabel');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('launch', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class'=>'crText crW320 crRequired'));?>

<?php echo $this->Form->label('pfd_c', 'Personal Flotation Device <span class="crRed">*</span>', 'crLabel');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('pfd_c', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>array(0, 1, 2), 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class'=>'crLegendText3'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('pfd_p', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>array(0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes'), 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class'=>'crLegendText3'));?>
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is not a jQuery error message at all, this is an html5 **required attribute**:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Sometimes CakePHP can set it automaticaly from validation rules. If it is not, then you can set it manualy by puting *'required'=>true* in your options array. Here is a solution for your example:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('pfd_c', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>array(0, 1, 2), 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class'=>'crLegendText3', 'required'=>true));?>
```

But keep notice that not all browsers supports **required attribute**, so you may want to leave an div error messages for these browsers.